# What is an "Askan?"

Tags: words, rabbis, yeshiva-school

What is an "Askan?"  I have heard this phrase in relation to well-know Yeshivot and rabbis, but have no idea who an "Askan" is.

Comment: People who help out in the community,many times finically

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An עסקן is a community activist i.e. someone who is "**osek** b'tzarchei tzibbur" עוסק בצרכי צבור (cf Mi Shebaurach after Yekum Purkan prayer before Shabbos musaf where this expression is found)